# replace a attribute value in dom element

Tags: jquery, attributes

I want to replace one of the attribute of anchor tag to different value. How can i achieve this. 
I used `replaceWith()` of jquery where it will replace complete anchor tag itself instead of attribute and 
"replace" method of string am not able to use it since we cannot call this on element.

code below:

```
this.ui.$levels.each(function(i, el) {
            var $self = $(el),
......
..
}
```

here self has html element, I need to modify one of the attribute value.

attr() of jquery should do. But problem is if I use $self.find('a').attr('id',' val'), it will replace in all anchor tag.I don't know which anchor to replace, I need to search for the specific id, if id is present then only it should replace.

Ex:consider $self contains below code snippet

```
  <div class="abc">
     <div class="xyz">
       <a href=# id="repplace_id"></a>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Here I need to modify the id of anchor tag to some other value. Please help

Help is appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using `$self.attr('href','new value');`. Just change `href` to the actual attribute you want to change.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. If I use $self.attr('href','new value'); or $self.find('a').attr('id','new-id'); $self.find('a:first').attr('id', 'newValue');, it will modify the id accepted but if I have another anchor tag inside <div>, it will add an attribute id to that. That is what the problem am facing.                        Ex:  <div class="abc">
     <div class="xyz">
       <a href=# id="repplace_id"></a> <a href=# ></a>
    </div>
   </div>. it attr() will replace the attribute if it is present, if attribute is not present it will add the attribute.

Comment: I see. So the problem is that you don't know which `a` to change? If there are several?

Comment: Exactly, Wherever the id is present , I need to place that.

Comment: I suggest that you update your question since it renders all current answers wrong or incomplete.

Comment: yeah updated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$self.find('a').attr('href','new value');
```

It will search for the a tag in the given html block and put the href attribute value as specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify elements attributes in jQuery using [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) like so:

```
$self.find('a:first').attr('id', 'newValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
$(".xyz a").attr("id","new_id");
```

This will replace only a tag inside the .xyz class

Answer (score 0):

Here you got two alternatives, depending on your scope.

One method iterates through $levels and changes all anchors where id has a value.

The other method finds a specific anchor based on it's previous id.

> But problem is if I use $self.find('a').attr('id',' val'), it will
>   replace in all anchor tag.I don't know which anchor to replace, I need
>   to search for the specific id, if id is present then only it should
>   replace.

Based on the quote above you probably just want to search for the id-attribute and use the `replaceSpecific`-method in the snippet.

```js
var $levels = $('.abc');

replaceAllThatExists();
replaceSpecific('new-id', 'yetAnotherId');

// If you don't know the specific id, and only want to change all if not exists.
function replaceAllThatExists()
{
  $levels.each(function(i, el) {
  var $self = $(el);
  var $anchors = $self.find('a');
    $anchors.each(function(i, a){
      var $a = $(a);
      if($a.attr('id')) {
          var currentId = $a.attr('id');
          $a.attr('id', 'new-id');
          console.log('changed id from: ' + currentId + ' to ' + $a.attr('id'));
      }
    });
  });
}



// If you know the specific id
function replaceSpecific(id, newId) {
  $levels.find('[id="' + id + '"]').attr('id', newId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="abc">
     <div class="xyz">
       <a href=# id="repplace_id1"></a>
       <a href=#>Does not have id</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="abc">
     <div class="xyz">
       <a href=#>Does not have id</a>
       <a href=# id="repplace_id2"></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="abc">
     <div class="xyz">
       <a href=# id="repplace_id3"></a>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i will have a look :-)